# Cypress font-size difference in last decimals

Tags: font-size, cypress

I am running Cypress tests in Chrome, in Win10 and only in my environment, the font sizes are different in cypress in the last digits, like in the attached picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95O2Q.png) than in Chrome.

**My display settings:**

- 100% scale
- 1920x1080 (Recommended) resolution
- and landscape orientation

I tried to run when I used only my laptop's screen and also when I extended the desktop, but in every scenario, the same issue happened.

The following snippet results it:

*element().should('have.css', 'font-size', '32px');*

Do you have any idea what can produce it and how can I handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Electron instead of Chrome. That solved it for me.

[image]